# how should i be able to use visual studio 2015 in the ".net core" debug and breakpoint c++ source?

Tags: c++, .net-core

I use the ".net core" for the development, the need to call the c++ dll library (I have the dll project source) I use the call is "DllImport", how should i be able to use visual studio 2015 in the ".net core" debug and breakpoint c++ source?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you enabled native debugging in the runnable project preferences?  If so then it should already be setup.

Comment: The following is my operation:Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable "Edit and Continue" and Enable "Use Native Compatibility Mode" and Enable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".But still can not debug c ++ code.

Comment: My case is C # call c ++ project, the whole project is started from the C # project.

Comment: There is one more place, in the C# project preferences you should see something like "Enable native code debugging" in the Debug section (Although I'm not 100% sure this option is there for .NET core...).

Comment: I have tried, but it is invalid.

Comment: Can you successfully debug? Can you post a sample project to GitHub?

Comment: Invalid how?  You mean the option is not there?

Comment: I mean that in accordance with the above steps set, still can not breakpoint.